# PostgreSQL 10 - return part of column (TEXT) value with matched ILIKE pattern and it's N neighboring words

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I'm trying to achieve something similar to what Google search does when displaying a result, so under a title and an url we got a short preview of text with matching words from the search string.

Text data example:

> Normally if you have all the **relation**ship setup properly between models and reflection table objects, you will only need to deal with related models (by appending model objects into the relationship InstrumentList) in order to insert data into reflection tables.

User input:

> relation

Result:

> Normally if you have all the **relation**ship setup properly between models

For now, I came up with the following (very poor) implementation:

```
SELECT id,
    COALESCE(
        (regexp_match(text, '(?i)\s.*?(relation.*?\s(\w+\s+){3})'))[1]
      , (regexp_match(text, '(?i)((\w+\s+){3}relation.*?)\s'))[1]
    ) AS text
FROM drafts.draft
WHERE
    text ILIKE '%relation%';
```

I'm really not good at regexps so it shows only the next words (not previous) and if we change 3 to 8 for the given text above it returns not 8 words but more (I think that is because of a comma in the text). Also, it returns NULL if there are less then N words left till the end of text.

---

**Resume:**

Given a text of a random length we want to set parameters `match, N`, where `match` is our substring and `N` is a number of words we want to have from each side (before, and after) first matched phrase in the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `substring()` to extract based on a pattern.  This appears to do what you want:

```
select substring(str from '((\w+\W){0,3}[\w]*relation[\w]*(\W[\w]+){0,3})')
from (values ('Normally if you have all the relationship setup properly between models and reflection table objects, you will only need to deal with related models (by appending model objects into the relationship InstrumentList) in order to insert data into reflection tables.')) v(str)
```

Comment: It's much cleaner with ```substring```. Thank you!

Comment: I added a ```(?i)``` to the beginning of regex to have a case-insensitive behavior similar to ILIKE (that I have later in the WHERE part). Maybe it also will help someone.